# Convert SVG into PNG in Perl

Tags: image, perl, graphics, svg, png

Having a `SVG` file I would like to convert such graphics into `PNG` format and print it to output (not file), with option to set `width` or `height` of the PNG image (in pixels), keeping the original aspect ratio of SVG graphics. How can I do this in `Perl`?

Comment: @mpapec: No. Image::Magick does not support all features of SVG. Might fail. I did this using something external. Let me go look it up.

Comment: convert command on windows will do that for you in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SVG::Rasterize](https://metacpan.org/pod/SVG%3a%3aRasterize). I've done this with complex SVGs using [Apache batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), which is built in Java.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick has reasonable  SVG support with the **rsvg** library as backend. Make sure you have it installed.